# ETL Tool for transfering old Firebird Database to a new organized Firebird Database

Tags: ms-access, firebird, etl

After looking at a lot of questions..i found no real answer for this.

I redisigned an Database for our customer.
With Microsoft Access i found a good Tool to get old table Data in my new well formed Database Structure. It is really easy but takes a lot of time (cause handling old Data with a lot of care).

Are there any Open Source Tools that bring that facilities like Microsoft Access?

To clear it up: I "just" want to reorder old Firebird Database Data in a new "best-practise" Way.

**Edit:**
I would be really nice if i can get a Log File or something similar to have some documentation on the changes.

**Update:**
After checking some of the Tools of that Wikipedia Site. I found no real Logging Mechanism.
How do you documentate the changes on a Database? Simply by writing it down?

**Result:**
So i dont got an real answer...i ma still searching for an nice tool. thnak you guys for the hints and your thoughts regarding this question. I want to reward Kenneth Cochran with the Bounty cause he pointed me to ETL. Thank you!

Comment: Old firebird database in Firebird 1.5 and new will be Firebird 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're asking for is an ETL(extract, transform, load) tool.

Wikipedia has a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load#Open-source_ETL_frameworks) of open source tools that may help with this. I've not used any of them personally.

Comment: +1 Thank you for that answer. Really helpful to point me in the right direction. Edited Question Header...:-)

Answer (score 2):

Talend's Open Source ETL supports FireBird. Very cool tool.

http://www.talend.com/download.php?src=DataGovernanceBlog

Answer (score 1):

Well, I used the Pentaho suite for doing ETL using their Kettle tool.
It's quite easy to use and should be more than enough to reach your intent.
And it's open source.

Give a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use a tool like [IBExpert](http://www.ibexpert.com) or [Database Workbench](http://www.upscene.com) which are the best tools for Firebird.

For migrating Firebird 1.5 to Firebird 2.1 : you just have to make a backup of your database with Firebird 1.5 server and restore your database with Firebird 2.1 server

Answer (score 0):

I've used Excel in the past to document data model changes - each worksheet used the application version in order to sync with our tags in CVS.  Every thing was logged in it - columns that were removed as well as minor alterations to datatypes like varchar(10) to varchar(20) etc along with a note describing why the change was made.

Personally, I've only ever scripted things like these as DDL/DML scripts broken into a script that dealt with table creation, constraint dropping, index drops, DML script(s), constraint application, index application, and removing orphaned tables.

Comment: Yeah it is a possible solution, but first Excel s not Open Source.
On the other hand i think that Excel was not designed for this issue. But thanks for that "possible" Solution.

Comment: I missed the Open Source requirement, but there is the Spreadsheet component of OpenOffice/etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want a basic ETL tool, that is client based (and cheap at $300), look at Advanced Query Tool.  It mainly queries any type of ODBC connection(including Excel files set up that way), but also has some extended features, including moving data.  And has a command line interface.  http://www.querytool.com/

I've used it instead of Informatica for one-off jobs, but I've also used to extract from Excel to another file for business users, for a few months, scheduled from my desktop.